# C# lambda extract a single row string value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Want to extract the text value from a lookup table's column in a db. EL is the entity for my db. Current code :

```
var QTypes = EL.ElogQueryType.Where<ElogQueryType>( eqt=> eqt.ID == queryTypeID);                       
string qType = QTypes.First().QueryType;
```

I get a list when I just pull `.Select(...`    so something is wrong.

Comment: I assume you don't really want the `First` since there is no `OrderBy` but instead want to just select back a `Single` record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just do if you know you will be just getting one item:

```
var QTypes = EL.ElogQueryType.Where(eqt=> eqt.ID == queryTypeID).Single().QueryType;
```

If you are not sure if you will get one or nothing use `SingleOrDefault()`.

If you just want the first since you are expecting many records do:

```
var QTypes = EL.ElogQueryType.First(eqt=> eqt.ID == queryTypeID).QueryType;
```

Same applies if you don't know if you will get anything, use `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what's wrong, as your current query should give you what you're after. However, you can also use the overload of `First` which takes a predicate:

```
string qType = EL.ElogQueryType.First(eqt => eqt.ID == queryTypeID)
                               .QueryType;
```

You say you "get a list when [you] pull .Select(" but it's not really clear what you mean. You haven't said what's wrong with the code you've already specified.

(As Kelsey says, there are alternatives to First: `FirstOrDefault`, `SingleOrDefault`, `Single` and even `Last` should you wish.)